# iOS sync calendar with google calendar at local app

Tags: ios, calendar, synchronization, google-calendar-api

I'm writing an app to sync with the built-in calendar.app using event kit. The built-in calendar.app will sync with Google Calendar when opening. However, my app will not sync with Google Calendar when opening.

Is there any method to sync with Google Calendar through the built-in calendar.app in code (open my app, and it will sync with Google Calendar without any setting)?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS5 EKEventStore have refreshSourcesIfNecessary method.